# Smack api and Openfire server presence error

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am developing a chat application using Smack api and I got stuck at receiving presence packets.

---

**Tested with Smack 3.2.2 and 3.3.0.**
These problems involve only using Openfire server 3.8.1.
**First**:I am sending the presence packet from Spark and receiving it with success 
**second** I am updating and sending presence packet from Spark client to my own:

```
<presence id="b8nyI-95">
   <status>Free to chat</status>
   <priority>1</priority>
   <show>chat</show>
   <x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update">
     <photo>d37b60faea717f9f7ca08bef1504d2de68a789eb</photo>
   </x>
   <x xmlns="jabber:x:avatar">
     <hash>d37b60faea717f9f7ca08bef1504d2de68a789eb</hash>
   </x>
</presence>
```

and receiving back in Spark debug :

```
<presence id="b8nyI-95" to="test2@localhost/Spark 2.6.3" from="test3" type="error">
 <error code="404" type="CANCEL">
   <remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
 </error>
</presence>
```

no packet is received in my own client.
This appears only when I try to update my presence in Spark.

---

**testing with another xmpp server :** *I think it's ejabberd* 
**Sending presence from Spark :**

```
<presence id="B0ANe-55">
 <status>Free to chat</status>
  <priority>1</priority>
 <show>chat</show>
</presence>
```

**Receiving it into my chat app **

```
<presence from='test2@maxciceu.p1.im/Spark 2.6.3' to='test3@maxciceu.p1.im/Smack' id='B0ANe-55'> 
 <status>Free to chat</status>
  <priority>1</priority>
 <show>chat</show>
</presence>
```

---

Both rosters have subscription set to :**both**
-with **Openfire** I am able to : connect, receive roster list (it gets the presence that is at the moment of initialization), send and receive messages, send files .
---can't do : update roster presence: tried with RosterListener and reloading the roster into my list

---

I've added a RosterListener

```
   Roster roster = Client.getClient().connection.getRoster();
   roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
     @Override
    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    @Override
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    @Override
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    @Override
    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
        System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);

    }
});
```

->Doesn't work when updating the presence of rosters with Openfire // with the other server everything is fine.

->also added (don't know if it helps or not with my problem):

```
    ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    if (sdm == null){
         sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);}
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#item");
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/caps");     
    JingleManager.setJingleServiceEnabled();
    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
```

---

Already went through Google and StackOverflow.

If anyone can help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved after a system reinstall.
I did a clean install of ubuntu and installed Openfire using this tutorial :http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-im-voip-server-using-openfire-ubuntu-1204.